# why I cannot drop procedure from different schema using drop procedure statement in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, schema

As simple as it is :

```
 drop procedure schemaName.procName
```

Gets the following error msg:

Msg 3701, Level 11, State 5, Line 2
Cannot drop the procedure 'procName', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
Edit: I tried also using Sql based authentication - still does not work

Strange that I am able to drop the procedure via the GUI.

I do have permissions - I am running with Windows authentication as sysadmin

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to offer ideas to you about why this would be acting like this.  What you can do is open SQL Profiler, and create a Trace on the SQL:StmtStarting/BatchStarting, RPC:Starting, and SP:Starting,StmtStarting events and actually capture the drop being issued by SQL Server Management studio through the UI and then compare that to the DDL that you are trying to manually write.  At least then you will know exactly how SSMS is doing the drop.